Understanding "the self-nature of phenomena is not found in the conditions"
In Cracking The Walnut: Understanding the Dialectics of Nagarjuna, Thich Nhat Hanh explains how in the four conditions out of which a phenomenon arises (seed condition, continuity condition, object of cognition as condition, supportive condition) we can not find the self-nature of the phenomenon itself.
The text which he is explaining, The Verses on the Middle Way by Nagarjuna, conclude this about the matter:


The self-nature of phenomena 
is not found in the conditions. 
Since there is no self-nature, 
how could there be an other-nature?


To illustrate this point Thich Nhat Hanh uses the example of fire.

For example, we may look for the self-nature of a flame in a box of matches. In the box are matches made of wood and sulfur. Outside the box is oxygen. When we search inside the wood, sulfur, and oxygen can we find the self-nature of the flame? Whether the match has already been lit or not, we cannot find this self-nature. What we call the self-nature of something cannot be found in its conditions at all.

My question is, how can Nagarjuna make the leap that because self-nature is not found in the causes or grounds out of which a phenomenon arises that therefore said phenomenon does not possess self-nature? For instance, if we at first assume that objects possess a separate self-nature and we take the example of ice instead of fire, we see that the conditions out of which ice arises (freezing temperatures, water, air pressure) do seem to possess something resembling the self-nature of their product. This is why I am confused when Thich Nhat Hanh uses the example of fire to illustrate the point -- surely there are other phenomena, like ice, which don't fit the rule?

@fake My intention was to use "causes" and "conditions" as roughly synonymous, maybe I worded something confusingly?

Let me attempt to rephrase it...so in the original text Nagarjuna says the self-nature (svabhava) of a phenomenon (dharma) is not found in its conditions. Thich Nhat Hanh in his annotation corroborates by giving the example of fire, the production of which depends on certain conditions (e.g. matches, oxygen) which don't share the self-nature (hot) of fire. But if this example is meant to prove Nagarjuna's statement, surely we can find examples like ice which apparently run against the rule?

So, don't try to fit other examples to the same process. It's like when someone says monkeys have five fingers same as humans, other person saying, but if we take fish, they don't have five fingers, so, they don't fit in to the description.
Of course they won't fit, that's why speaker didn't use fish for the example.

I have read this:


There are four conditions: efficient condition; Percept-object condition; immediate condition; Dominant condition, just so.  There is
no fifth condition.


So first you can match up the pairs. I'll guess like this:

Efficient condition ~= seed condition
Percept-object condition ~= object of cognition as condition
immediate condition ~= continuity condition
dominant condition ~= supportive condition

Maybe that helped but here is alternate translation of your OP:


The essence of entities Is not present in the conditions, etc.... If there is no essence, There can be no otherness-essence.


Then from 70 verses:


Essence arising from Causes and conditions makes no sense. If essence came from causes and conditions, Then it would be fabricated.

How could it be appropriate For fabricated essence to come to be? Essence itself is not artificial And does not depend on another.

If there is no essence, How can there be difference in entities? The essence of difference in entities Entities are established



Back to an earlier stanza:


If there is essence, the whole world Will be unarising, unceasing, And
static. The entire phenomenal world Would be immutable.



"ontological independence is what is known as 'self'"

I don't know Nagarjuna's dialectics, unfortunately.
Perhaps an answer is that, "a separate self-nature" ought to be permanent -- if ice really had the "separate ice nature" then that should be so even when conditions change.
Think of "self-nature" as being like, "the immortal soul" or "essence" of ice.
Instead of being permanent though, you observe that iciness is "conditioned" -- "something" is ice when it's cold, something else when it isn't. There is no "ice" except conditionally.
IIRC Thich Nhat Hanh tries to explain that everything is something else -- e.g. "ice" is water vapor plus winter, and so on.

+1 "a separate self-nature" ought to be permanent

This is well-explained by Ven. Thich Nhat Hanh in his writing entitled The Heart Sutra: the Fullness of Emptiness:

If you are a poet, you will see clearly that there is a cloud floating
in this sheet of paper. Without a cloud, there will be no rain;
without rain, the trees cannot grow; and without trees, we cannot make
paper. The cloud is essential for the paper to exist. If the cloud is
not here, the sheet of paper cannot be here either. .....
If we look into this sheet of paper even more deeply, we can see the
sunshine in it. If the sunshine is not there, the forest cannot grow.
In fact, nothing can grow. Even we cannot grow without sunshine. So we
know that the sunshine is also in this sheet of paper. The paper and
the sunshine inter-are. And if we continue to look, we can see the
logger who cut the tree and brought it to the mill to be transformed
into paper. And we see the wheat. We know that the logger cannot exist
without his daily bread, and therefore the wheat that became his bread
is also in this sheet of paper. And the logger’s father and mother are
in it too. When we look in this way, we see that without all of these
things, this sheet of paper cannot exist.
Looking even more deeply, we can see we are in it too. This is not
difficult to see, because when we look at a sheet of paper, the sheet
of paper is part of our perception. Your mind is in here and mine is
also, so we can say that everything is in here in this sheet of paper.
You cannot point out one thing that is not here — time, space, the
earth, the rain, the minerals in the soil, the sunshine, the cloud,
the river, the heat. Everything coexists with this sheet of paper.
.....
When Avalokita says that our sheet of paper is empty, he means it is
empty of a separate, independent existence. It cannot just be by
itself. It has to inter-be with the sunshine, the cloud, the forest,
the logger, the mind, and everything else. It is empty of a separate
self. But, empty of a separate self means full of everything. So it
seems that our observation and that of Avalokita do not contradict
each other after all. Avalokita looked deeply into the five skandhas
of form, feelings, perceptions, mental formations, and consciousness,
and he discovered that none of them can be by itself alone. Each can
only inter-be with all the others. So he tells us that form is empty.
Form is empty of a separate self, but it is full of everything in the
cosmos. The same is true with feelings, perceptions, mental
formations, and consciousness.


Through the cloud of cataracts I see the wisdom in  Ven. Thich Nhat Hanh's own words. Thank you for quoting!

Analogy is just an analogy. It is not the exact picture. Having said that , the Truth remains that Sabbe Dhamma Anatta, meaning all conditioned and unconditioned phenomena are not Self.
For instance , take the example of body. Body is made up of bones , muscles , brain, eyes , tongue, ear, nose etc.
Not just that there is ear consciousness, tongue consciousness, nose consciousness, eye consciousness. It is combination(components of combination here can be understood as conditions)of these phenomena which results in the phenomena called body. These combinations are impermanent. Body and it’s physical and non physical components are impermanent. That which is impermanent is suffering. That which is suffering can not be called Self.
Therefore all conditioned and unconditioned phenomena are not self.

I will use autonomous & independent instead of self nature. Ice isn't an independent object apart from it's conditions (water, cold etc). If something removed cold (or added heat) from ice, ice disappears. Similarly if we remove water from Ice, Ice also disappears. Without supporting conditions Ice doesn't exist.
Anything dependent of other conditions to exist can not be said to independent & autonomous. If they are autonomous & independent they alone should determine their properties(not others).
Suppose such independent essence exist. Since they are independent they are not affected by other phenomena and they do not change due to others. Thus they are permanent.

Part 1  :: Explanation
Example like that are very specific and picked by the speaker very carefully. So, most of the time, any other examples won't fit the description.
So, don't try to fit other examples to the same process. It's like when someone says monkeys have five fingers same as humans, other person saying, but if we take fish, they don't have five fingers, so, they don't fit in to the description.
Of course they won't fit, that's why speaker didn't use fish for the example.
Remember, those are just examples, which only used to make it easier to understand by others, about some other concept.

Part 2 :: Method
That's a method used by teachers.

Some well known            Some very  
common process         =   complex hard
(eazy to understand)       problem



So the listeners can understand the hard problem easily. (because they can correlate well known process to hard one ) .

Part 3 :: Extra
Example is only used to explain base problem(which he/her is trying to explain(self nature in this qusetion)) .

This is why I am confused when Thich Nhat Hanh uses the example of fire to illustrate the point -- surely there are other phenomena, like ice, which don't fit the rule?


surely there are other phenomena, like ice, which don't fit the rule?

There are infinite number of phenomena in the world. All of them won't fit here. Some may fit.
Remember that, there's no connection between fire nature and self nature of the mind. This is just an example.
